# Continuously change the title of a cmd window in the background

Tags: vb.net, cmd, titlebar

I use the code down below to start a cmd window and then change it's title. This works, but the new title is changed back to the default title, as soon as you use a copy/paste function in this window.
So I'm looking for some code which changes the title *after* completing MyBase.load and which continues running in the background, as long as the cmd process exists. However, I do not know how to do this.
Can somebody help me out here with some kind of example? Thanks for any help in advance!

Kind regards, Eric

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lpString As String) As Integer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim h_wnd As Integer
        Dim proc As New Process
        proc = Process.Start("cmd.exe")
        Thread.Sleep(10000)
        h_wnd = proc.MainWindowHandle
        SetWindowText(h_wnd, "My new Window")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The CMD Caption is probably changed back to the original value at the first *interaction*. You could send a mouse input to the Window, with, e.g., `mouse_input` + `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` + `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` with absolute coordinates relative to CMD Frame, then `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` and `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP` with empty coordinates. Set the new Caption after that -- Not clear why you're using `Shell()` here (isn't that thing deprecated?), you should call `Process.Start()`, which returns a Process object from which you can get the handle of that Window

Comment: Hi @jimi The title is _not_ changed back when I enter input. Only when I use the mouse and select one or multiple characters. I read on multiple sites that changing the title of a cmd window is not persistent.
I used shell() because the original code was made in VB6, but you are right, I should (and will) change it to Process.Start().

Comment: Isn't that what I said? *Interaction* -> with a Mouse, hence I suggested to first send a Mouse input using, well, [mouse_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) (that now I realize I previously named `mouse_input`, LOL) -- The Caption should remain *stable* after, since `conhost.exe` already had its shot

Comment: Hi @Jimi I altered my code above, switched to Process.Start() and implemented a 10 seconds delay before changing the caption. It gives me time to do a manual click in the cmd window, which is basically the same as what you suggested in your reply, right? If so, it doesn't work. As soon as SetWindowText is executed, the caption is changed to `My new Window`, but as soon as I click anywhere in the screen (or enter shift-right arrow), the caption changes to `Select c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`. Pressing escape makes the caption change to `c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`, not to `My new Window`.